# How to connect to a running instance of outlook from C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, excel-2007, office-interop, outlook-2007

In VBA, I usually use `appOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")` to get a running instance of Outlook, and it throws an error if Outlook isn't running. I normally did this in excel, but now I am wanting to see if I can get better results by moving to C# and doing it from there. What I need to do is copy emails from outlook and paste them into excel so that the tables in the email get pasted into the spreadsheet as cell values rather than html. However, I'm not quite sure how to do this. I usually use `Activator.CreateInstance`, but it makes a new instance. How can I connect to the current instance of Excel and Outlook?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getactiveobject.aspx) for this purpose.

(See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3770784/501250).)

Comment: This throws `Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))`

Comment: @ArlenBeiler: Is Outlook running?

Comment: Yes. Actually, turns out one can't be running as administrator and the other normal, they both have to be the same. Thanks

Comment: @cdhowie can we add that last comment by Arlen to the answer?  It just saved me endless agony and I almost overlooked it entirely!

Comment: is there any simple easy way to check this condition, i.e., permissions match between client and server?

Comment: @drdbkarron Yes, just catch the specific exception.

Comment: Exceptions are expensive operations I want to read permissions from both sides and check if the bitmasks are congruent ($them together).

Comment: @drdbkarron Pretend that you proceed with the route of catching the exception. How many exceptions do you expect to be generating per second?

Comment: how did you solve it finally?